Regular curve with curvature of $0$?
Working through Taimonov’s Lectures on Differential Geometry. Exercise is to prove that a curve is biregular iff its curvature is nonzero.
Biregular is here defined as having nonzero first and second derivatives. Curvature is defined (for 3D) with the cross product.
Intuitively and mathematically, I find a curve parametrized by t defined as a scaling of any constant vector by $e^{t}$ has curvature $0$ and nonzero derivatives.
That is, $\gamma=e^{t}*\vec v$.
How is this possible?

A consequence of biregularity is that the curves $\gamma'$ and $\gamma''$ must be linearly independent. You found a curve where this is not the case. Intuitively, you might be asking, "well then why does the curve you found seem to be acceptable, but isn't"?
The answer is that the definition you have listed for biregular applies to curves parametrized by their arc-length, not all curves. There's a more complicated version of biregularity that can be applied to curves that aren't parametrized in a very special way, but that definition gets kind of gross. Also curves parametrized by their arc-length can be quite painful to have to generate interesting examples from, so I understand your frustration.
But intruitively you are on the right track with your example. Specifically, the thing we know to have zero-curvature is a line. So regular curves get rid of weird cusps. By extension, biregular curves get rid of the next thing ... zero curvatures.

Ah, I suppose the definition of biregular presented in the book does say ‘a regular arc length parameterized curve’ etc. and indeed if that’s the case my example (I believe the only example in general, per soln. of the differential equations associated) doesn’t fly. What threw me off was the question (a three parter) specifying that the curve was NOT an ALP, but I suppose invoking biregularity forces me to add that condition to my assumptions.

Also out of curiosity would you have that other definition?

Technically you can use what I wrote above as the definition of biregularity for curves that fail to be parametrized by their arc lengths. And then you'll actually get the result of the above, that is, non-zero curvature.
